# Tableview is not displaying data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

**SecondVC.swift**
this is the code file for the `tableview` and slider view but `tableview` data is missing in output.
Please help me with this.
The code seems perfect but still, the cell is not displaying the content fetched from the database.
The cells are getting displayed but no content is shown them
Actually, the number of cells displayed is not equal to `fields.count`.

[image: O/p + Main.storyboard]

[image: File Hierarchy]

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class SecondVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sideView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var field = [Fields]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:
        Int) -> Int {
        return field.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
        IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"SecondVCcell")
        cell?.selectionStyle = .none
        cell?.textLabel?.text = field[indexPath.row].Field_fieldname
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = field[indexPath.row].Field_fieldvalue
        return cell!
    }

    var name : String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
        blurView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        sideView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        sideView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        sideView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width : 5, height : 0)

        viewConstraint.constant = -175
        loadData()
    }

    func loadData()
    {
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid


        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any]
        {
            let fieldV = dict["fieldN"] as! String
            let fields = Fields(fn: snapshot.key , fv: fieldV)
            self.field.append(fields)
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func PanGestureTriggered(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {



        if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed
        {
            let translate = sender.translation(in: self.view).x
            if translate > 0
            {
                if viewConstraint.constant < 20
                {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                        self.viewConstraint.constant += translate/10
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    })
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if viewConstraint.constant > -175
                {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                        self.viewConstraint.constant += translate / 10
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        else if sender.state == .ended
        {
            if viewConstraint.constant < -100
            {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    self.viewConstraint.constant = -175
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }

                )}
            else
            {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    self.viewConstraint.constant = 0
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
                )}


        }
    }
    @IBAction func SignOutTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        if firebaseAuth.currentUser != nil
        {
            do {
                try firebaseAuth.signOut()
            } catch let signOutError as NSError {
                print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
            }
        }
        if firebaseAuth.currentUser == nil
        {
            let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",
                                       bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as!
            ViewController
            self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func HomeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.viewConstraint.constant = -175
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        )}
    @IBAction func unwindSegue(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection method is getting called ?

Comment: What is the result of field.count?

Comment: If the count is 0 in numberOfRows, then cellForRow will not be called

Comment: Number of cells will be as big as the tableview, unless you set `tableView.footerView = UIView()`

Comment: In your `loadData()` function what is the value of `dict`. If it is `nil` then that's the problem.

Comment: You need to create class for tableviewCell name "SecondVCcell" and then take tableviewCell inside tableview and set its class with "SecondVCcell" and reuse identifier with "SecondVCcell"

Comment: Or if you are not using custom cell then just put this code snippet below let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"SecondVCcell") this

if cell == nil {
               cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

Comment: Although information is not clear, here are some possible suggestions.

1. try to check value of "dict", if it has not any content, then your tableview will not reload. Try to print field.count in console.

2. From your snippet, it seems like, you are using custom cell, if this is the case, you need to register cell as mentioned.

3. Try to separate delegate/datasource code by extension of your viewcontroller, so it become easy to understand.

4. if field.count is not zero then, try to check cell == nil condition and display static content in textlabel and detailTextLabel for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom table cell then you haven't register Nib.

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"")
```

If you are using prototype cell then you must getting field array count 0